# How can I send data from a server to all connected clients?

Tags: python, twisted

I have an extremely basic TCP server setup in Twisted.

```py
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class Server(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print(f"Received data {data}")
        self.transport.write(data)

factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
factory.protocol = Server
reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
reactor.run()
```

I would like to make a function that sends data to all connected clients, and I imagine to do this I first need a list of all the connected clients which I can iterate through and send data to each. So how can I get this list of clients to send data to them?

Comment: I don't see any evidence of an actual protocol.  You are just echoing whatever data comes through without trying to interpret it.  Do you have a protocol in mind?  Writing a TCP socket server must either involve a fixed length data protocol, a delimiter based protocol, or the client must close the connection after sending data.  Since I don't see evidence of the first two, I wonder if you aren't relying on the third option.  If you are, then there will be no connected clients.

Comment: According to my client, it says I have a constant connection. This is me just trying to setup a basic server so I can add it a PySide6 GUI, which will do stuff with the server. Out of curiosity, what are delimiter and fixed length data protocols?

Comment: Your question about protocols suggests to me that you don't have one in mind.  If you don't have a protocol in mind, it does absolutely no good for you to have an open socket connection...especially one that stays open and performs multiple rounds of request/response.  You have to know what protocol your client is going to talk to you with.  If you can pick the protocol, then you have to pick one.  To do otherwise is like dialing a telephone, having someone pick up on the other end, and then you don't share a common language, so you can't make any use of the phone connection.

Comment: To answer your question...there are hundreds of protocols in the wild.  There are many fewer well known ones used all the time. Well known ones are HTTP(S), MAIL, DNS, SSH, SCP, FTP, etc.  The most generally used protocol these days is HTTP, and that's likely what you'll want to use.  You've heard of REST?  That's sort of a sub-protocol on top of the HTTP protocol that adds extra rules and best practices on top of the basic protocol HTTP protocol.

Comment: Oh, the plan was to use a TCP protocol. My plan is to have one UI as a server and other UI's as clients that can connect and send data to the server, and the server can send data to all connected clients in response. I was going to use HTTPS but that isn't a constant connection which I think I need, mainly to identify different clients.

Comment: TCP is a "Transport Protocol". It provides you with a pair of streams of bytes, one going from client to server, and one going from server to client.  It has nothing to do with interpreting the bytes that travel along those streams.  TCP is the "telephone".  TCP isn't your answer to choosing a protocol.  You still need to choose a "Presentation or Application Protocol". This is "English", "Spanish", etc.  You can't implement communication over a TCP socket if you don't know what protocol you're speaking.

Comment: The simplest of protocols is "line-based".  Each request consists of a single line, terminated by an EOL character.  Each side reads bytes until it reads a EOL character, at which point it knows that it has read 1 entire request/response.

Comment: Got any reccomendations for what I should use then? I don't really know anything about networking. I just need to send data back and forth between clients and servers and have the server be able to send data to all clients.

Comment: To know for sure what you should use, I'd have to know more about what you're doing.  HTTP APIs are the most common way these days for two programs to talk to each other.  Due to the fact that there are dozens if not hundreds of frameworks available that let you write a HTTP client or server in just a few lines of code, this option makes sense for many applications. See section 1.3 here for a list of simple frameworks for building HTTP APIs: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks. Sections 1.1 and 1.2 provide lists of more "full stack" frameworks that offer more than just communication.

Comment: OH...Duh!  Twisted has implementations of various protocols, including HTTP.  Check this out: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.0.0/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html - This article seems kinda cool: https://www.stxnext.com/blog/beginners-introduction-python-frameworks/

Comment: Oh that twisted one looks very promising. I guess I avoided HTTP since my implementation idea included starting a flask server and checking for POST requests. Although I suppose that's basically what it is, but I'm not sure how to check a list of "connected clients" since HTTP just sends data and I don't have access to the IP, right?

Comment: You should have access to the IP.  I'm not sure exactly how, but Flask should give you a way. - You might want to consider having your clients poll...that is, contact the server periodically to say "have any messages for me?".  That would let you avoid having a second set of everything to do the communication back to all the clients. - If you're thinking of putting this out on the internet, where people you don't control have clients, contacting them by initiating a connection is likely not always possible.

Comment: Well I was originally going to use TCP, but I think HTTP is the way to go. Thank you very much. I didn't get what I came for, but I got what I needed.

Comment: I want to make sure you understand.  TCP and HTTP aren't the same sort of thing.  In fact, HTTP rides on top of TCP.  Most protocols on the web ride on top of TCP.  TCP is not something you have to know exists as a programmer.  Saying you're doing a "TCP protocol" doesn't mean much.  It's like saying "I'm going to store my data in files".  That says nothing about what's in the files. TCP says nothing about what's being communicated.  All of the protocols I mentioned earlier are protocols that normally ride on top of TCP.  The main other protocol is UDP, a connectionless protocol.

Comment: Have fun!  I recommend that you read a networking book some day to have all of this clearly presented from the lowest to highest level.  See: https://www.webopedia.com/reference/osi-layers for a quick look at networking's various levels.  TCP is a layer 4 protocol.  HTTP is either layer 6 or layer 7, depending on who you ask.  Any protocol you made up yourself on top of a socket (TCP) would be considered either 6 or 7 as well.